# How to using XGoogleChart in Yii

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I tried to used  XGoogleChart for create pie chart in Yii, i really want to create pie chart like this tutorial http://www.eha.ee/labs/yiiplay/index.php/en/site/extension?view=charts, and i tried made  simple code like this :

```
<?php
$data=Stock::model()->findAll(array("select"=>"t1.item_name,stock",
                                              "join"=>"JOIN tb_dtl t1 ON   
                                                       t1.brg_id=t.brg_id",
                                              'limit'=>5

 ));

$items=array();
foreach($data as $i)
{
   $items1=$i['item_name'];
   $items2=$i['stock'];
   $items[]=array($items1 => $items2);
}

$this->widget('application.extensions.XGoogleChart',array(
    'type'=>'pie',
    'title'=>'Inventory',
    **'data'=>$items,**
    'size'=>array(400,300), // width and height of the chart image
    'color'=>array('6f8a09', '3285ce','dddddd'), // if there are fewer color than slices, then colors are interpolated.
));

?>
```

The problem  is the chart no display, what wrong with my code, any body can help me. Thanks

Comment: Any console error ?..

Comment: Is your extension registering css's and javascripts?

Comment: No error display, actually if i tried code like below,chart running well :

    $this->widget('ext.widgets.google.XGoogleChart',array(
        'type'=>'pie',
        'title'=>'Market 2008',
        'data'=>array('IE7'=>22,'IE6'=>30.7,'IE5'=>1.7,'Firefox'=>36.5,'Mozilla'=>1.1,'Safari'=>2,'Opera'=>1.4),
        'size'=>array(400,300), 
        'color'=>array('6f8a09', '3285ce','dddddd'),
    ));

the problem when i tried change array code 
    'data'=>array('IE7'=>22,'IE6'=>30.7...,
 

chart only show Label, Thanks